# ssh config 'Missing target argument'

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to run the equivalent of this:

`ssh -L 4200:localhost:4243 root@192.168.1.4`

In an SSH Config file:

```
Host crashplan
HostName 192.168.1.4
LocalForward 4200:localhost:4243
User root
```

But when I run `ssh crashplan` I get the error:

`line 4: Missing target argument.`

Comment: Apologies! When I think "technical help" I think to come to StackOverflow. Won't happen again.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp (maybe your comment got migrated?! but as of where your comment is currently) it appears to be on-topic because it is not related to programming!

Comment: @barlop indeed the whole topic has been migrated. I'll remove the comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Valid config format is this:

```
LocalForward localhost:4200 localhost:4243
```

I have solved the same issue right now :-)

Comment: This also helps with the same error message with `RemoteForward`